# Is there a special program i can use to make games on android? Or should i just use JOGL?

Tags: android, jogl

Is Jogl the best way to create an Android Game such as a 2d game?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say anything about the 'best' way, but you can use

- andengine,
- Corona,
- Maoi,
- Unity3d,
- OpenGL ES 1.0/1.1/2.0, or
- Draw to a [Canvas or View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html).

[Beginning Android Games](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430230428) is probably the single best resource (especially chapters 3&4).  You should also look at the SDK samples (snake, lunar lander). [Practical Android 4 Games Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430240296) is... not good (the copyediting is particularly shameful), but it is at least devoted to game development with OpenGL ES.